# Resposive web design floating element distance

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a number of div's (cell_container) that has fixed length and width.
They are located inside a wrapper that take 90% of body width. If you resize browser, some element goes to next line. And this is ok. But some free space is left on the right. How to make margins auto or dinamically change distance between cell_containers, thus elements located with same distance from each other and edges.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="cell_container">
        A   </div>
    <div class="cell_container">
        B   </div>
    <div class="cell_container">
        C   </div>
    <div class="cell_container">
        D   </div>
    <div class="cell_container">
        E   </div>
    <div class="cell_container">
        F   </div>
    <div class="cell_container">
        G   </div>
.....
```

CSS:

```
.cell_container
{
    width:150px;
    height:220px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:5px;
    border:1px solid;
    border-color:#999999;
    cursor:pointer;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: if the design is responsive then `.cell_container` shouldn't have a fixed width but in percentages so you can use @media queries to adapt to the parent container when it resizes

Comment: It is still :) I have to keep .cell_container as fixed. It's number in line thought is variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use the `text-align:justify` trick.

```css
#wrapper {
    text-align:justify;
    width:90%;
}
#wrapper::after {
    display:inline-block; width:100%; height:0; content:'';
}
```

This will align all the lines in the wrapper div to both sides, including the last line.

http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/v3T2s/1/

Of course it only looks good when all the lines have the same number of elements; in this case (with 7 inner divs), it won't look good when there's more than one line.
Like JFK says, to make it truly responsive, you should give the inner divs a width in % too. But that is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

I know you already chose your answer, but I think a more elegant approach would be to use `text-align:center`. Since inline-block elements behave like text, you can have your div elements centered at all times no matter how many you have (even in odd numbers) by simply adding `text-align:center` in the wrapper.

[SEE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/iamjosan/y2BZ6/)

```
#wrapper{
width:90%;
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;

}
```